# Manage a server for notification system using PHP ratchets web sockets

Tags: php, server, notifications, ratchet

Is it possible to achieve an online real-time notification system based (small scale)website which implements PHP ratchet websockets?

Locallly on my machine I start my PHP server using command prompt, but how could this be done for a hosted website?

As i will not be able start and maintain a server 24X7 for all remote clients, how would this actually work?(I dont have enough knowledge in this area)

Am i missing out on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code for notification feature:

```
    <script>
        if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") 
        {
            var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
            source.onmessage = function(event) {
               notification(event.data);
              };
        }
    </script>
```

And ofcourse you will need demo_sse.php which will be useful for fetching and storing data to the database.